# Node.js REPL funny behavior with custom eval function

Tags: javascript, node.js, read-eval-print-loop

It seems that Node.js (version v0.10.13) returns the command wrapped between `(` and `\n)`, here's a minimal example:

```
require('repl').start({
    'eval': function (cmd, context, filename, callback) {
        callback(null, cmd);
    }
});
```

The behavior is the following:

```
$ node repl.js
> asd
'(asd\n)'
>
```

Why is that? If this *feature* is [documented](http://nodejs.org/api/repl.html) then I was not able to find it.

Also, if this is the intended behavior, is there a better solution than doing `cmd = cmd.slice(1, -2);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is already fixed (see [commit 9ef9a9de](https://github.com/joyent/node/commit/9ef9a9dee54a464a46739b14e8a348bec673c5a5) from Aug 2013). Now only JSON expression is wrapped into parens.

Comment: Fixed in the unstable version.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you can capture `stdin` stream to a variable and use it instead. I think node does it because user input supposed to be a js expression, which is good to be wrapped in closure `()`.

```
var buffer = '';

process.stdin.on('data', function(chunk) {
  buffer += chunk.toString('utf8');
});

require('repl').start({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout,
    'eval': function (cmd, context, filename, callback) {
      console.log(buffer);
      buffer = '';
      callback(null, true);
    }
});
```